# Slick carousel hides last slide during a resize, slickGoTo not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I'm implementing Slick Carousel and it works fine except for just one issue. If I've got a list of slides, I select the last one in the list, then I resize the window, the active slide gets hidden.

I have a variable `currentSlideIndex` that keeps track of which slide is active (it gets set when a user selects a slide).

An attempted solution I have acts during every resize event, and contains this logic:

```
_.defer(function() {
  myCarousel.slick('slickGoTo', currentSlideIndex, true);
});
```

For some reason though, this isn't working, as the active slide still remains hidden and if I want to see it I have to drag through the carousel to find it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this problem before. The only solution I could think of is to cache the slide the user is on, destroy the slideshow with `unslick`, reinitialize it with your settings and then go to the slide that you were just on. Works great for mobile orientationchange.

```js
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  var currentSlide = $slick.slick('slickCurrentSlide');

  $slick
    .slick('unslick')
    .slick(slideSettings)
    .slick('slickGoTo', currentSlide)
  ;

});
```

Comment: This did work, not as elegant as I'd like but a solution non-the-less!